# JavaScript 1 Time Interval?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, dom-events

```
window.onload = setInterval(myFunc, 5000);
function myFunc(){
    alert("This is a test.");
}
```

Is there any way to stop the function after 1 interval or to just have it perform 1 interval?

Comment: Use `setTimeout()` instead of `setInterval()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setTimeout`

```
window.onload = setTimeout(myFunc, 5000);
function myFunc(){
    alert("This is a test.");
}
```